# tvOS and NavigationSplitView not working properly

Tags: swift, swiftui, tvos, navigationsplitview

I tried NavigationSplitView in tvOS but as you can see it goes full screen with a sidebar and it does not display the details column, what I'm doing wrong?

```
struct ListViewDetails: View {
   
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: .constant(.doubleColumn)) {
            Color.blue
        } detail: {
            Color.red
        } 
    }
}


[![img][1]][1]
```

[image]